# Authorization Failed in Twitter

Tags: android

I am implementing Twitter api in android, I have generated new api and consumer key but this returns the error "This happend only is consumer key is wrong or signature is different".

Code:
OAUTHREquestTokenTask.java

```
package com.ex.softZilla;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An asynchronous task that communicates with Twitter to 
 * retrieve a request token.
 * (OAuthGetRequestToken)
 * 
 * After receiving the request token from Twitter, 
 * pop a browser to the user to authorize the Request Token.
 * (OAuthAuthorizeToken)
 * 
 */
public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;

    /**
     * 
     * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
     * 
     * @param   context
     *          Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
     * @param   provider
     *          The OAuthProvider object
     * @param   consumer
     *          The OAuthConsumer object
     */
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to authorize the token.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I too got the same problem. I think this is because of request token url as twitter changed their  Request token URL from http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token to http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token.

But official doc says Request token URL is http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token. But the sample app is failed. I think it is it is he reason.